# bash, pass an argument to the 'history' command

Tags: bash, awk, alias, command-history, function

I do the following to make history more sensible (i.e. seeing when a command is run can be fairly critical when troubleshooting)

```
shopt -s histappend;   # Append commands to the bash history (~/.bash_history) instead of overwriting it   # https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-history-commands-and-expansions-on-a-linux-vps
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"   # -a append immediately, then  -c clear history, then -r read history every time a prompt is shown instead of after closing the session.
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T  " HISTCONTROL=ignorespace:ignoreboth:erasedups HISTSIZE=1000000 HISTFILESIZE=1000000000   # make history very big and show date-time
alias h='history';   # Note: 'h 7' will show last 7 lines
```

This is fine, but I want to be able to get the original history output if I need it. This works for `ho` ("history original"), but I can no longer do "ho 7"

```
alias ho="history | awk '{\$2=\$3=\"\"; print \$0}'" # 'history original'
```

So I tried the following, but this fails with errors:

```
function ho() { history $1 | awk '{\$2=\$3=\"\"; print \$0}'; } # 'history original'
```

How can I create an alias or function that will allow me to do `ho 7` and I'll just see the last 7 lines?

Comment: `alias ho() {...`? Is that an alias or a function?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. You are defining a function, but using the `alias` keyword. Just remove the `alias` and you should be fine. Next, you are escaping the awk variables, but you aren't double-quoting, so the escapes are being passed to `awk`. This is what you're after:

```
ho() { history "$@" | awk '{$2=$3=""; print}'; }
```

Comment: The `alias` was a typo (I was doing a correct `function` declaration in my script); the changes that you suggest don't work unfortunately, tested now, entering `ho 7` just results in a stuck command prompt and I have to `Ctrl-c` out of.

Comment: @YorSubs that's strange. I just tested this, both by copy/pasting directly into a terminal and by adding it to my `~/.bashrc` and it works fine. The only issue is that `ho` alone complains about needing a numeric argument. Changing `$1` to `$@` fixes that (see updated answer). Are you _sure_ you copied the exact same code?

Comment: Works, thanks. I coped the exact same code, but I suspect that my history aliases were all messed up as I was trying to many different things, rebooted WSL now and all working perfectly, thanks.  Both your and muru's answers help me, but yours most completely answers the case where I want to modify with awk/sed etc.

Answer (score 2):

By "history original" I assume you mean you want the output without timestamps. If so, just set `HISTTIMEFORMAT` to empty for `history`:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT= history
```

In an alias,

```
alias ho='HISTTIMEFORMAT= history'
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks, this does fix it, and I did not know that syntax like this was possible, so this is very useful. .